# Seemingly equal delegates change finalization in Mono

Tags: c#, mono

Struggling with some managed/unmanaged fusion and trying to be especially careful with callbacks into managed code, I have come across a strange difference in how two seemingly equal (until today) delegates interfere with GC in Mono. To make the story short, here is a code snippet:

```
using System;

class A {
    public Action f;

    ~A() {
        Console.WriteLine("~A");
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var a = new A();
        Action f = delegate {}; // Instantiating a delegate
        a.f = f; // Assigning the delegate
        a = null;

        Console.WriteLine("GC start");
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        // 'a' has been finalized here
        Console.WriteLine("GC done");
    }
}
```

I get the expected output:

```
GC start
~A
GC done
```

But if I collapse the two lines which instantiate and assign a delegate into one, i.e. eliminating the use of an explicit local variable:

```
        var a = new A();
        a.f = delegate {}; // Instantiating and assigning a delegate
        a = null;

        Console.WriteLine("GC start");
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        // 'a' has NOT been finalized here
        Console.WriteLine("GC done");
```

I get unexpected output in Mono 3.2.4:

```
GC start
GC done
~A
```

So it looks like the second form (without using an explicit variable) implies an additional reference to the object somewhere whereas the first form uses an explicit local variable and is thus technically more susceptible to the observed anomaly.

I checked the same EXE on Windows and it works as expected. Slightly confused right now whether it is a subtle distinction in Mono or a bug because the code couldn't be more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono scans the stack for references in a more conservative way than the .net runtime, so it may happen in cases like this that there is either a false reference to the object or a hidden reference (in intermediate code/local var generated by the jit). Usually you can solve these kind of issues by allocating the object in a separate call frame, but case 1 can still apply. This is almost never a problem except in simple tests programs as above.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Indeed, I wrapped the piece with a separate call, and it now behaves predictably. I am just picky on subtleties. I know, for most people it's not worth spending time, but it has always worked well for me in terms of the ultimate quality of programming.